# how to create a pdf file contains image and table using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

```
public void genreatePdf()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>");
        sb.Append("<tr><td><img src='images/my.jpg'/></td></tr>");
        sb.Append("<tr><td>some text</td></tr>");
        sb.Append("</table>");

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/invoice/invoice.pdf");
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph(strMailMsg.ToString()));
        document.Close();
    }
```

output of pdf file is

```
<table><tr><td><img src='images/my.jpg'/></td></tr><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>
```

qus: The expected format is like a table with image and text in it. Why the pdf file not getting created on that format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table and append it to the pdf file. Its not done via appending XHTML, use C#'s internal tables.

```
Table aTable = new Table(2, 2);    // 2 rows, 2 columns
theTable.AddCell("0.0");
theTable.AddCell("0.1");
theTable.AddCell("1.0");
theTable.AddCell("1.1");

//add the table to the document
document.Add(theTable);
```

[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18040/Tutorials-on-creating-PDF-files-using-C-2-0) is a simple tutorial with itextsharp.